# ¿Cómo utilizar una función agregada agrupando por datos 'implícitos' en SQL?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Buenas tardes a todos.

Quisiera saber que comandos de SQL son requeridos para que a partir de la relación principal se pueda obtener la relación derivada.

F.A. es una función agregada cualquiera y por los datos que aparecen no es difícil determinar cuál es (es la suma de número de exámenes por genero), pero mi verdadera duda recae en cómo podría agrupar para obtener los resultados mostrados. He intentado mediante operaciones sobre cadenas y agrupando sobre paciente pero no llego a un resultado.

Gracias. 
[image: Relación original]
*Tabla 1: Relación principal.*

[image: Relación derivada]

*Tabla 2: Relación derivada.*

Comment: tienes algun campo que identifique el género de los registros? es decir que ayude a separar los registros por hombre y mujer?

Comment: Desafortunadamente no, solo se tiene lo que aparece en la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

si no tienes un campo que identifique el género de los registros. Se puede hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
select Genero, [F.A] = SUM(NumeroDeExamenes) 
from ( select Genero = case when Paciente IN ('Camilo','Ricardo') then 'Hombre'
                            when Paciente IN ('Alexandra','Maria') then 'Mujer'
                   end,
          Paciente,
          Aseguradora,
          NumeroDeExamenes,
          Total
       from RelacionPrincipal ) TablaNueva
group by Genero
order by Genero desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esta respuesta es buena pero limitada que va a pasar cuando el número de pacientes y por ende nombres aumente a cientos de miles o incluso cientos? y que existan nombres parecidos, me parece que el diseño de la base de datos debería ser replanteado